# Powershell for linux - what is a viable terminal to launch it from?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, powershell

I am on Ubuntu 20.x using Powershell 7.x latest.

I am currently using "Terminator" program as the terminal program I launch it from, then I launch powershell by typing `pwsh` from there.

I'm having some intermittent problems with powershell on linux and it may be due to terminator.

Is there a more suitable terminal program I should be using with powershell 7?

This is *not* an opinion based question. I'm not asking what is everyone's favorite. I'm asking which one is viable... as I'm having intermittent issues with the programs that I run from Powershell being killed with no explanation when I'm using terminator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use VScode, add the Powershell extension, set the config to use pwsh as the default on launch.

This is all covered in the VSCode docs. It's not just a terminal, it is first and foremost an IDE, that you can use with multiple different terminals.

> Download Visual Studio Code - Mac, Linux, Windows
> https://code.visualstudio.com/Download
> https://code.visualstudio.com/docs
>
> Running Visual Studio Code on Linux
> https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/linux
>
> Integrated Terminal
> https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal
>
> Managing multiple terminals
> https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_managing-multiple-terminals
>
> vscode powershell linux development
>
> https://duckduckgo.com/?q=vscode+powershell+linux+development&t=h_&ia=web
>
> Youtube videos on the topic.
> https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=vscode+powershell+linux+development